# What's the best way to design a recursive function that generates all combinations of n-digits numbers?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

As part of my Algorithms course in collegue, we have to design a recursive function that generates all combinations of n-digits numbers.

This is an example:

Sample input:

> 3

Sample output:

> 111
>
> 112
>
> 113
>
> 121
>
> 122
>
> 123
>
> 131
>
> 132
>
> 133
>
> 211
>
> 212
>
> 213
>
> 221
>
> 222
>
> 223
>
> 231
>
> 232
>
> 233
>
> 311
>
> 312
>
> 313
>
> 321
>
> 322
>
> 323
>
> 331
>
> 332
>
> 333

I would like to point out that I've already solved this problem, so that people won't comment that this is homework and I must do it on my own.
Anyway, here is my code in C++ :

```
void S6_1(int r, int n, int p, int d)
{
    if (d == 0)
        return;
    S6_1(r, n, p, d - 1);
    r = r * 10 + d;
    if (p == 1)
        cout << r << endl;
    else
        S6_1(r, n, p - 1, n);
}

void S6(int n)
{
    S6_1(0, n, n, n);
}
```

The main reason I post this is the fact that I strongly believe that there must be another way to solve this problem.

I really appreciate any help you can provide

Comment: Please use real variable names.

Comment: I strongly believe there must be another way to solve political conflicts than applying war. Give me a solution please.

Comment: I assume a positive number must be provided? You solution segfaults on negative numbers, either handle negative number or use unsigned int

Comment: So why is 999 not the last 3 digit number?  Some other rules not mentioned?  Hex not allowed?  Octal not allowed?  a 3 bit number is much smaller set.

Comment: Your output is incorrect. You're missing 131, 132, 133, 231, 232, 233.

Comment: If you have n digits, there are n^n n-digit numbers. Another way to think of the problem is counting from 0 to (n^n)-1, and converting each number to base-n. You can easily map 0 to 111, 1 to 112, etc.

Comment: I missed those numbers, I forgot to add them in the post. Sorry about that.

Comment: I also thought about converting each number to base-n, but I coulnd't come up with something that works with recursivity. If you know the algorithm, please let me know. I will appreciate it.

Comment: Note that this can be solved iteratively without too much difficulty. After all, you can count to 1000 without using recursion.

Comment: I know, but the point of this problem is to solve it by using recursion.

Answer (score 3):

Think inductively: How do you separate the problem of generating all n-digit numbers with digits in [1..n] into a smaller instance of itself plus a little more work? Perhaps the most obvious is to tack all possible digits onto the front of all (n-1)-digit numbers that are recursively generated. I'll use C (but C++ is similar) to accumulate the numbers in a buffer one at a time.

```
// In buf[i..n-1], enumerate all numbers having n-i digits with values in [1..n]. 
void print_all(char *buf, int i, int n) {
  if (i == n) {               // Here n - i == 0, so we're done. Print.
    printf("%.*s\n", n, buf);
    return;
  }
  for (int digit = 1; digit <= n; ++digit) {
    buf[i] = digit + '0';     // put a digit at position i
    print_all(buf, i + 1, n); // recursively put the rest
  }
}
```

To call it:

```
char buf[n];
print_all(buf, 0, n);
```

It's also fine to build the number in an `int` as you did. The code is a bit shorter, but it leaves the job of decomposing the `int` into a string to `printf`, so in a sense it's double work:

```
void print_all(int b, int i, int n) {
  if (i == n) {
    printf("%d\n", b);
    return;
  }
  for (int digit = 1; digit <= n; ++digit) {
    print_all(10 * b + digit, i + 1, n);
  }
}
```

And to call it...

```
print_all(0, 0, n);
```

**Edit**

As I pointed out in comments, replacing obvious loop applications with recursion that's harder to understand is not smart. But since you asked,

```
// Enumerate all numbers formed by appending to the number in b all (n-i)-digit
// numbers starting with a digit in [d..n] and all other digits in [1..n].
void print_all(int d, int b, int i, int n) {
  if (d > n) return;
  if (i == n) {
    printf("%d\n", b);
    return;
  }
  print_all(1, 10 * b + d, i + 1, n); // enumerate all with more digits
  print_all(d + 1, b, i, n); // enumerate other values of i'th digit
}
```

And to call:

```
print_all(1, 0, 0, n);
```

Comment: Thank you for replying to my post.  I was recently reading a book about algorithms and it said that recursive functions shoulnd't have iterations or loops.

Comment: @Drako I'd throw that book away. It's a stupid statement. While it's possible to replace any loop with a recursive function call, there's no reason to do so. Use recursion when it makes your program simpler to write and understand. Otherwise use a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is good but there are so many variables. I would use recursion like this:

```
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

void rec(int i, int n, int number){
    if(i == n) {
        printf("%d\n", number); //newline
        return; //another n digit number completed
    }

    for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++){
        rec(i + 1, n, number * 10 + j); // *10 + --> adds the new digit
    }
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char *args[]){

    int n = 3; //read n from input
    rec(0, n, 0); //this will go n level in depth and before going on each level prints one digit

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you try running this, you'll see it doesn't work... even if you set `n` to have some value.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I edited my code :). It works now. I should have kept the whole number as well. If you may want to deal with n >= 10 or perhaps symbols A to F (for base 16). You can use a vector <char> instead of int for number argument and when i == n print the whole vector.